# Plotting a bar with pandas & matplotlib on R: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am currently figuring out how to use pandas and matplotlib with R. I did a reconstruction of instructions given on how to plot a bar with some given csv data. All calculations work perfectly. Plotting the bar gives me an error:
TypeError: `Series.plot()` should not be called with positional arguments, only keyword arguments. The order of positional arguments will change in the future. Use `Series.plot(kind='bar')` instead of `Series.plot('bar',)`.

This command is given to us:

```
train_data['Pclass'].value_counts(sort=False).plot('bar') plt.grid()
```

But what it it returns is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

So I tried to seperate plt.grid(), but get the error mentioned:

```
TypeError: `Series.plot()` should not be called with positional arguments, only keyword arguments. 
The order of positional arguments will change in the future. 
Use `Series.plot(kind='bar')` instead of `Series.plot('bar',)`.
```

Step-by-step, what I did:

```
#Import Module Pandas
import pandas as  WORKS
import matplotlib as plt WORKS

#Load the Dataset
train_data = pd.read_csv("train.csv") WORKS
train_data = train_data.set_index("Name") WORKS

#Print the Data-Head
print(train_data.head(31)) WORKS

# get the shape of the data set
train_data.shape WORKS

# get the data types
train_data.dtypes WORKS

# get the first entry
train_data.iloc[15]  WORKS

#frequency table
train_data['Pclass'].value_counts(sort=False) WORKS

# bar plot of passenger classes (absolute)
train_data['Pclass'].value_counts(sort=False).plot('bar')  DOES NOT WORK

plt.grid() DOES NOT WORK
plt.title('Absolute Häufigkeiten der Passagierklassen') WORKS
```

Does anyone have an idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `train_data['Pclass'].value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: did you use `plot(kind='bar')` instead of `plot('bar')` ?

Comment: it would be simpler if you would use `#` in code to add information as comment `# WORKS`. This way we can simply copy and run code.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, you have answer in error message.

You have to use `plot(kind='bar')` instead of `plot('bar')`. That's all.

```
train_data['Pclass'].value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

---

As for first error: in Python you can't put two commands in one line.
You could use `;` to separate them but it is no preferred.

You have to put `plt.grid()` in new line. That's all.

---

**EDIT:**

I found another mistake: you forgot `.pyplot` in

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```